# Get data from external site and then modify it

Tags: javascript

If somesite(external site) returns a string like "cost is 10$", would it be possible to display it as "price:10$" using only javascript and on my own site? 
External site is facebook.com or something.
My site is my site.

---

Hey guys. I am editing a question. I want to get data FROM external site. I donnt need just modify string it's easy, of course. I need something like.

> var str =
>   GetData("http://facebook.com/blablbal");
>
> str.Replace('blbablab','blabal');
>
> ShowToUser(str);

I hope you understand me. Sorry i'm not a native speaker.

---

I mean get data using XMLHttpRequest or iframe and then modify it. One of the moderators edited my question and replace title. But he donnt understand what i actually mean.

---

Here is real example.

http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?act=count&index=[index]&url=http://talismansochi2014.ru/grandfather_frost/go.php returns

> VK.Share.count(0, 8718);

i want to get 8718 and show user just number 8718. And i can use only JS. I cannt make request from server and then return webpage.

---

Maybe i need recreate question or provide some additional information?

Comment: Its about to get real in here. Do you have any code your currently using?

Comment: I'm sure it is real. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Are you asking for the way to retrieve data from another website? Or only how to modify the string? Well you could do two things in JS anyway.

Comment: ha no actually, came up with Loktar back in the WC2 days :P

Comment: @Louskan yeah i want to get data from other site and show modified data ot user.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
"cost is 10$".replace(/cost is /, "price:");
```

That should return "price: 10$".

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always the same could just do:

```
var string = "price:"+returnString.substring(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="cost is 10$";
document.write(str.replace("cost is","price:"));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `alert('price:'+('cost is 10$').match(/\d+/)+'$')`, replace cost is 10$ with var that holds this string